# Test Automation tool not running via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, ranorex

Here is a general description of the issue which I cannot solve:

We have a WindowsServer 2008 R2 system that is used to running the install of our product(using powershell script), and then the Powershell script calls the .exe of our UI test automation tool (Ranorex).

The install of the product works fine, but the UI automation portion only runs if some is physically logged in via remote desktop.

If the remote desktop session is closed (but the programs continue to run..so user is technically logged in), the UI automation portion will NOT run.

The options I selected on the General tab of the job are:

-Run only when the user is logged in;
-Run with highest privileges;

Any ideas on from anyone who has had this issue and got it to work would be extremly helpful.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Why don't you use the TestAgent (in `Interactive Mode`) of TFS 2010 or TFS 2012 to run your UI automation & other build stuffs ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx

Comment: We use Ranorex for UI automation, so this would not be an option for us.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I thought one can integrate Ranorex into any CI process - http://www.ranorex.com/blog/tag/team-foundation-server. More here - http://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager

Comment: I have used Hudson/Jenkins in the past to execute QTP automation, and it worked.  Thanks for the suggestion - I will give Jenkins a try since I am familar with that tool.

Comment: Hi Angshuman, I tried to use Jenkins to kick off the automation, but the job will not launch the browser.  It seems to be trying to run in the background.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know anything about Jenkins. May be you can contact the Ranorex support.

Answer (score 0):

UI operations are usually in suspended state when a user is disconnected from an RDP session. Use a tool like VNC or equivalent where you have access to the main console for these UI operations to remain active.

Comment: Can the VNC session be close and will the UI operations still work?

Comment: Yes, make sure the console does not lock out on timeout and you will be fine